# Determining how far an actual value is from a predicted value as $x$ increases

Tags: regression, standard-deviation, residuals, error

Assume you have 5 $x$ values `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and 5 $y$ values `(1, 2, 1.3, 3.75, 2.25)`. From this you estimate a linear equation of $y = 0.775 + 0.425 \cdot x$. You then determine the standard error to be $0.747$.

We can determine how far a value is from its expected in terms of standard errors, but it seems to me that the *magnitude* of $x$ should also be taken into account. For example, if $x=1$, $y$ is probably going to be pretty close to $1$, and likely no further than 1 or at most 2 from its predicted value. But if $x$ is 100, it could easily be 10 or 20 away from its predicted value.

So I am asking for the formula that if, say $x = 100$, and we predict $\hat{y} = 43.25$, but we observe $y=49$, how far is $49$ from $43.25$ in terms of standard errors?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Some pointers: (1) You can use formatting to make your question more readable, I edited your question for this. (2) You don't have to thank and/or sign your answers, have a look at the tour. (3) Simple linear regression assumes that variance is more or less the same along the regression line (homoscedasticity), which is why you would expect the deviation from $\hat{y}$ to be the same, regardless of $x$. If you don't want this, then you shouldn't be using simple linear regression.

Comment: Your question incompletely specifies the regression model which may be why you have a confusion (or at least why the answer to your question may not be obvious). In particular, $y$ represents *observations* and $y$ does not therefore equal *either* the population line $\beta_0+\beta_1 x$, nor does it equal the fitted line  $\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1} x$. Instead, the model is $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\epsilon$, and it is the assumptions about the error term (or equivalently the conditional distribution of $y$ given the value of $x$) that determine how you model the standard error. ...ctd

Comment: ctd... You *seem* to be anticipating a particular kind of variable (e.g. I'd guess from the sound of it you're thinking of a response variable $y$ that is necessarily positive) in which case it would be expected that there's more variation about the mean line when the that takes high values than when it's smaller. Which is to say *whether* it makes sense to consider the magnitude of x in describing the behaviour of $\epsilon$ depends on the circumstances, which you have not specified. You may also wish to consider that necessarily positive values are also likely to be skewed (at specific $x$).

Comment: ctd ... In addition, with necessarily positive values, it's often the case that the relationship with $x$ might tend to curve (flatten off) as the mean gets small (since it can't remain linear -- that would imply it could at some point pass through zero). It may help potential answerers if you clarify a little about the circumstances you're considering that led to your suppositions, which might make for a more responsive answer